# register_shutdown_function not called when the exit happed in external function

Tags: php

i have a class, and in that class i have a shutdown function registered as the follow

```
class test{
    function __construct() {
        $self = $this;
        $shutdown = function () use (&$self) {
            $self->shutdown();
        };
        register_shutdown_function($shutdown);
    }

    public function shutdown()
    {
        echo 'shutdown';
    }

    public function doThing(){
        $tools = new tools();
        $tools->loadUrl('https://google.com');
    }
}
```

tools class

```
class tools {
    function loadUrl($url){
        include('url.php');
        return openUrl($url);
    }
}
```

url.php

```
function openUrl($url){
    //use the fsockopen function
}
```

this is the main files structure and i can not change it so please do not give me answers include change any thing related to changing the functions or structure

**the problem**
if the max exc time exceed the 30 second because of a function in the test class it will work fine,but the problem happen when the max excu time happen in the `fsockopen` on `openUrl` function, the shutdown function not called

Comment: how you are creating object of test class and where?

Comment: shutdown function will be called either if a fatal error is occured, i agree with chetan's comment we need to see how and when your Test's object is created

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should read PHP documentation note about stream operations and maximum execution time:

> Note:
>   The set_time_limit() function and the configuration directive max_execution_time only affect the execution time of the script itself. **Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution of the script such as system calls using system(), stream operations, database queries, etc. is not included** when determining the maximum time that the script has been running. This is not true on Windows where the measured time is real.

So as long as your connection is opened, the script won't finish and your shutdown function won't be called because the connection has not finished yet.

This might be the case if the host you are trying to connect is not responding or if the answer is slow.

If you want to define a timeout for your `fsockopen` call, you have to define the variable `default_socket_timeout` or use the fifth argument of the fsockopen function (http://php.net/fsockopen)